# android media player - PVMFFailure on mp3 http radio stream

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to play mp3 radio stream using Android MediaPlayer via http protocol. From time to time [1 playing of 5 - that is actually quite often] I receive PVMFFailure like this:

```
02-23 02:05:23.503: ERROR/PlayerDriver(91): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFFailure
02-23 02:05:23.503: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2111): error (1, -1)
02-23 02:05:23.533: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2111): stop called in state 0
02-23 02:05:23.533: ERROR/MediaPlayer(2111): error (-38, 0)
```

There is no solution here or on google, so please if you do know how to debug this, please help :)

Here is my code for player:

```
 //start
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
 player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 player.setDataSource(address);
 player.prepare();
 player.start();

 //stop
 player.stop();
 player.reset();
```

I`m using Android 2.2 API. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this: github.com/avafab/URLMediaPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You should use `player.prepareAsync();` instead `player.prepare();`.